# Keyboard arrow Navigation

Tags: java, html, css

My crossword is a table made with `<td>` tags. The input boxes are textboxes (input="text"), styled with CSS. My question is how do you get the focus to the next cell/textbox by using the keyboard arrows. (Up, down, right, left, and backspace)

Comment: This looks very similar to your [previous question about applying keyboard navigation to a crossword puzzle drawn with Canvas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/166038/how-to-use-arrow-keys-to-navigate-between-cells-in-a-crossword-puzzle). Have you tried applying a strategy similar to the answer there?

Comment: Yes it is, but didn't work so I rewrote the code so that the input cells could accept focus